# Maximum Likelihood in the Markov Switching GARCH(1,1) Model

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, garch, hidden-markov-model

In the standard GARCH(1, 1) model with normal innovations:

$${\displaystyle ~\epsilon _{t}=\sigma _{t}z_{t}},$$
$$\sigma^2_t=\omega+\alpha\epsilon^2_{t-1}+\beta\sigma^2_{t-1}.$$

The (negative) log-likelihood of $T$ observations occurring in the order in which they are observed is:

$$\sum_{t=1}^T\left[-\ln(\sigma^2_{t})-{\left(\frac{\epsilon^2_{t}}{\sigma^2_{t}}\right)}\right].$$

However, in the Markov switching GARCH(1,1) model with two regimes, the conditional variance is:

$$\sigma^2_{1, t}=\omega_{1}+\alpha_{1}\epsilon^2_{t-1}+\beta_{1}\sigma^2_{1, t-1},$$
$$\sigma^2_{2, t}=\omega_{2}+\alpha_{2}\epsilon^2_{t-1}+\beta_{2}\sigma^2_{2, t-1}.$$

My issue is that I couldn't find in any article or paper a similar expression of the (negative) log-likelihood function of the MS-GARCH(1, 1) model with normal innovations. I would really be thankful if anyone can guide me.

Comment: Hi: if you can get your hands on it,  check out nelson and kim's text. I vaguely remember that having the sort of thing that you're looking for. The title of the book IIRC is "Regime Switching Models".

Comment: I didn't have the title quite right. https://www.amazon.com/State-Space-Models-Regime-Switching-Gibbs-Sampling/dp/0262535505/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=nelson+and+kim+regime+switching+models&qid=1631763869&sr=8-1

Comment: the model is underspecified : what  are the switching probabilities? are they just 2 additional constant parameters or some functions of available information?